# What Bracha do you make on (Kasha) buckwheat?

Tags: food, blessing, halacha

What Bracha Rishona and Bracha Achrona do you make on (Kasha) buckwheat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This confuses everyone as it has the word "wheat" in its name, but [it's not related to wheat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwheat)!

It's not *chametz* on Passover, either (although it is [considered by some to be *kitniyot*](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-HandyKitniyosGuide2011.pdf)).

Assuming it hasn't been turned into mush (rendering it *shehakol*), *ha'adama* before, and *borei nefashot* afterwards. (Source: [Brachos.com](http://www.brochos.com/item/5529) cites *The Laws of B'rachos: A Comprehensive exposition of the background and laws of blessings* by Rabbi Binyomin Forst with Rabbi Aaron D. Twerski. Artscroll, p. 361 ISBN: 0-89906-220-2 (hard cover)
ISBN: 0-89906-221-0 (paperback))