# Halachic status of kamut

Tags: blessing, food, chametz-leaven, matzah, agriculture

[Khorasan wheat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khorasan_wheat), often known by one popular brand name thereof, [KAMUT®](http://www.kamut.com/en/trademark.html), is an ancient grain that is related to modern-day wheat, but has a number of differences. Does it have the halachic status of wheat, e.g., with regard to *chametz* and suitability for *matzah*, or whether its *berachah* is *hamotzi / mezonos*?

Comment: It has gluten, so I'd guess it's real dagan. Do you have any reason to assume not?

Comment: ...and chadash, birkat hamazon, challah...

Comment: @DoubleAA - just because the five species of dagan have gluten doesn't mean that anything with gluten is dagan. (This is especially true if *shiboles shual* is oats, which IIUC do not have gluten.)

Comment: Adderabba! If oats were dagan that would show that non-gluten things could be dagan, not that gluten things might not be dagan. I challenge you to find me anything that has gluten that is not dagan.

Comment: The next questions should be about the halachic statuses of eichut and mahut.

Comment: @DoubleAA my point is that you can't say that the definition of dagan is "grains which have gluten" if one of them doesn't. The fact that we don't know of any non-dagan with gluten doesn't mean that gluten is definitional to dagan (though it is admittedly strong evidence of being a related species).

Comment: @Dave I never said that the definition of dagan is "grains which have gluten". I'm arguing that it is logically sufficient to have gluten not logically necessary to have guten. Plus to point out from before, this assumes not only that oats are a dagan but that they always were a dagan, an even harder claim to defend.

Comment: Greetings from Kamut International - Your posts are very interesting and I am interested to learn more. I am a representative of Kamut International and wanted to share more about our grain and company. KAMUT® is the name of the BRAND, not the wheat. One of the biggest misconceptions about KAMUT® Brand khorasan wheat is that the name “Kamut” refers to the type of wheat, while in fact, KAMUT® is the trademark name. Bob Quinn, Founder of Kamut International, wanted to assure the quality of the organic, heirloom grain, khorasan wheat. (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) Under the brand KAMUT®, consumers know they can trust this wheat will always be grown certified organic, will always be non-GMO, and will never be altered or modified. KAMUT® brand khorasan wheat is grown under strict production guidelines and every field is tested for high quality standards. Go to http://www.kamut.com/en/trademark.html for more information about this including how “KAMUT” was picked as the name!

Comment: @Jamie, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for that clarification and additional information! I've edited the post to make it clear that KAMUT is a brand name. You might be interested to know that, as I alluded to in a pun comment above, "kamut" is also the Modern Hebrew word for "quantity."

Comment: @IsaacMoses Following the link Jamie provided, I see that there is reason to believe that the word is related to the Hebrew word Kemach (flour). That's quite interesting!

Comment: @Dave, Nice! maybe they should merge with [Kemach Food Products Corp.](http://www.kemach.com/).

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10498/what-bracha-do-you-make-on-kasha-buckwheat

Comment: It is called **WHEAT**, not just a type of "grain" (like quinoa or a "grain" of corn)...  Do you have any reason to assume that it might not be considered as wheat for the purpose of the five grains?

Comment: @AdamMosheh http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10498/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - Thank you, interesting question over there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [CRC-Chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/passover_2011%20FAQ.pdf)

> Kamut is a variety of wheat which can become Chametz if mixed with
>   water and left unattended for 18 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Like any fruit, wheat can have different varieties. Just because it is larger or slightly easier to digest does not make it something else other than wheat. It grows the same way, it is harvested much the same way, it is ground to flour, and it is used for bread. While it's conceivable that the 18-minute rule for Matzah might need to be adjusted because of the unique properties of this variety of wheat (although I'm not suggesting that this is the case; I'm just pointing out one possible ramification that could be discovered in using a "different" variety of a grain), the same can be said of baking Matzah in different climates, using different sources of water, etc. In other words, while some might think to add new stringencies to account for differences, that does not mean it is a different thing than is "traditionally" used.

Comment: Is 18 minutes just for wheat, or for all 5 (wheat rye spelt 2- and 6-row barley)?

Comment: I suppose I should just [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's irrelevant to my answer, since, first of all, I was coming up with _some conceivable_ difference that ultimately doesn't really matter, and second of all, the point is about something that is (at least to the questioner) different from those things that are known to have that rule.

Comment: And [Gershon Gold has proven me wrong about an absolute source](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16952/5)!

Comment: Don't feel bad though; the fact that the only source we can find is in the last ~10 years gives a lot of credence to your argumentation.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, we're not going to find the word "khorasan" anywhere in the classic literature, so the best I can do for a proof that's based on sources more than 25 years old will have to utilize some indirect evidence.

I figure, if these two types of dagan (grain) [aren't kilayim](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%90) with each other:

[image: barley] [image: oats] 
 than certainly these two aren't! I bet you can't even tell which of these is the khorasan wheat:

[image: khorasan wheat] [image: regular wheat]

(pics from wikipedia)

I now assume that no non-dagan species can be non-kilayim with a dagan species. I have no proof to this, but I have no evidence of any counterexamples despite some time spent examining the kilayim possibilities of the different types of dagan in the Mishna cited above; additionally this principle seems very reasonable as I would think that their different statuses with regard to dagan would distinguish the two species enough to be different for the laws of kilayim as well.

Comment: I could see someone arguing, by the same logic, that barley is a type of wheat. It surely looks more like wheat than like oats! But in fact the Mishnah puts them in separate categories.

Comment: @Dave [I was not planning on bringing this up here, but you've just proven to yourself that Shibbolet Shua'l is not oats, but actually 6-row barley, while Se'ora is 2-row barley. This answer assumes as we discussed above that oats are Shibbolet Shu'al.]

Comment: @Dave Well if extreme similarity of appearance and taxonomy is not an indication of non-kilayim, then what is? Are you suggesting that we need to be machmir not to plant any variant cultivars together lest it be kilayim because we have lost the ability to properly distinguish species?

Comment: @Dave And as regards barley specifically: wheat and barley are in different geni (but the same family), while regular wheat and khorasan wheat are in the same genus, just different species. I am not a botanist, but I assume that means there are more physical similarities between the wheats than to the barley. To differentiate at the species level would be like to differentiate between bread wheat (T. aestivium) and noodle wheat (T. durum). (FTR wheat, both barleys, rye and spelt are all in the tribe Triticae. Oats are in the tribe Aveneae.)

Comment: I basically agree with everything you've said. It's just hard to know what criterion were used by Chazal to differentiate between species. Certainly the factors they focused on were not exactly the same ones that are used for modern classifications.

Comment: And just to throw something else into the mix - the Rishonim (in the beginning of Maseches Kilayim) say that the categories for kilayim don't necessarily carry over to other areas of halachah.

Comment: @Dave cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2825/759

Comment: "... in different geni ... " The plural of genus is genera. "Geni" is the rare vocative singular of "genius", as in "hey, genius." Not all Latin words ending in -us are masculine or second declension. "Genus" is third declension neuter.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genus#Latin